# Cross-compiling of C code for Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, libc, bionic

I cross-compiled my C application for *Android ARM* with *arm-linux-gnueabi* tool under *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*. I compiled it with static linking flag. This C application is big and it has complicated makefile. It compiled successfully without any errors. But it behaves **differently** on Android phone and Ubuntu PC. More precisely i have two problems:

1. `popen()` and `system()` functions don't work on Android. They are carried out but do nothing and don't give any errors. This problem i solved with dirty hack.
2. `fgets()` functions works strange on Android.

**1. About first problem.**

I did small research and found that Android doesn't use ordinary *libc*  library (*glibc* or another library which implements POSIX standard properly). It uses *Bionic* library instead of it (sorry, Android is new OS for me). I looked into `popen()` and `system()` functions code and noticed that these functions use `_PATH_BSHELL` macros. `_PATH_BSHELL` is path to the actual system shell. This path is "**/system/bin/sh**" on Android and "**/bin/sh**" on Ubuntu.

When i understood it i tried to hook `popen()` and `system()` functions. I copied code of these functions from the *Bionic* source, than i defined macros `#define _MY_PATH_BSHELL "/system/bin/sh"` and replaced calls like `execve(_MY_PATH_BSHELL, argp, environ);` by `execve(_MY_PATH_BSHELL, argp, environ);` calls. So it started work properly.

**2. About second problem.**

On Ubuntu this code works properly:

```
is_received = false;
while(!is_received) {
    FILE *cmd = popen(command, "r");
    is_received = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), cmd) == NULL ? false : true; 
}
```

But on Android `fgets()` always returns `NULL` and this loop works *infinitely long*. I tried to use `read()` function instead of `fgets()` and it worked.
On Android this code with `read()` works properly:

```
is_received = false;
while(!is_received) {
    FILE *cmd = hooked_popen(command, "r");
    int fd = fileno(cmd);
    is_received = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

**My questions.**

1. How to solve my problems with `popen()` and `system()` neatly and correctly? I think i have to link statically with *Bionic* library. Is it right? How can i do it in console without Android Studio? I read that it is necessary to use *NDK* but it is not clear to me how.
2. Why `fgets()` behavior isn't similar on Android and Ubuntu?